# iOS >> UILocalNotification Got Lost

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, appdelegate

In my App there may be a scenario where several Local Notifications will be fired very closely with a very close 'fire date'.

If the app is in the foreground, it seems that the AppDelegate catches them all, via the didReceiveLocalNotification method.

But... in case the app is in the background or closed, and I click on the 'popup' that pops in the home screen, this method only captures the first Notification, while the others seem to be lost; and I need them all...

Anyone?

Comment: can't you use userInfo of NSNotification?

Answer (score 0):

For local notifications did you tried below?

```
NSArray *pendingNotifications = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
        if ([obj1 isKindOfClass:[UILocalNotification class]] && [obj2 isKindOfClass:[UILocalNotification class]])
        {
            UILocalNotification *notif1 = (UILocalNotification *)obj1;
            UILocalNotification *notif2 = (UILocalNotification *)obj2;
            return [notif1.fireDate compare:notif2.fireDate];
        }

        return NSOrderedSame;
    }];
// if there are any pending notifications -> adjust their badge number
if (pendingNotifications.count != 0)
{
    //do something
}
```